# Tcl_Format memory usage

Tags: c++, tcl

Here is an extension proc for TCL written in C(++) (that it's C++ does not matter here – I just use `std::vector`).
I use `Tcl_Format` to create a new formatted string. If I don't use `Tcl_DecrRefCount`, Xcode reports more and more memory being used every time this external proc is called:

```
int TclME::vTestExt(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj* const objv[])
{
    Tcl_Obj *resultPtr, *item[1], *itemFormatted;
    size_t N;
    std::vector<long> v;
    populate_v(v);
    N = v.size();
    resultPtr = Tcl_NewListObj(0, NULL);
    for (long i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        item[0] = Tcl_NewLongObj(v[i]);
        printf("item[0] ref %i, sh %i; ", item[0]->refCount, Tcl_IsShared(item[0]));
        itemFormatted = Tcl_Format(interp, "#%06X", 1, item);
        // With Tcl_DecrRefCount commented out, there is a memory leak
        printf("\tref %i, sh %i; ", item[0]->refCount, Tcl_IsShared(item[0]));
        Tcl_DecrRefCount(item[0]);
        printf("\tref %i, sh %i\n", item[0]->refCount, Tcl_IsShared(item[0]));

        Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, resultPtr, itemFormatted);
    }
    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, resultPtr);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

`void populate_v(std::vector<long> &v)` sets the vector items.

The output is `item[0] ref 0, sh 0;     ref 0, sh 0;    ref -1, sh 0`, so I would not expect having to call `Tcl_DecrRefCount` manually.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new TCL object, its *reference count* is 0.

Any TCL object is subject to be freed when the reference counter *drops to* 0. So, the clean way would be to first *increment* the reference counter after creating the object and then *decrement* it again when it is no longer being used (after the call to `Tcl_Format()` for example).

In your special case above, you can circumvent this problem by using `Tcl_ObjPrintf()`:

```
...
for (long i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement(interp, resultPtr, Tcl_ObjPrintf("#%06X", v[i]));
}
...
```

Comment: wish I could give 2+, for `Tcl_ObjPrintf` and explaining the *drop* bit.

Comment: It used to be very annoying to generate this sort of thing; that's why `Tcl_ObjPrintf` was added.